# Synchronously get AccessToken from IHttpContextAccessor's HttpContext

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-security

We're using ASP.NET Core 2.2 to build a Web API project that effectively is a smart proxy for another API. We don't want to do anything special with access tokens though, and just forward them when calling the other API.

I want to avoid "sync over async" calls, especially in constructors and DI resolvers and factories, while still relying on the framework to handle retrieving access tokens from the current http request.

Here's a representative repro of our scenario:

```cs
public class TheOtherApi : ITheOtherApi
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public TheOtherApi(HttpClient client, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _client = client;

        // Yuck! Sync over async, inside a constructor!
        var token = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;

        client.SetBearerToken(token);
    }

    public Task<string> ForwardSomethingCool(MyCommand command)
    {
        // E.g.
        var response await _client.PostAsync(command.path, command.body);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Registrations in `Startup` along these lines:

```cs
services.AddScoped<ITheOtherApi, TheOtherApi>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped(_=> new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.org/api") });
```

This perfectly demonstrates my problem: there's a `.Result` in there, that I want to get rid of entirely, without just moving it to some kind of factory function registered in Startup.

Searching for a synchronous way to get the access token, I went down into the source of `GetTokenAsync(...)` and see what other method I could use intead. I find that it in fact has all sorts of side-effects, for example it does [`AuthenticateAsync(...)`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4649449206edae4992e09419334e736726fd2c8e/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/TokenExtensions.cs#L157) before doing what the method name suggests ("getting a token" from the context).

I actually only want the logic from `GetTokenValue(...)` without the other bits, and hurray (!): it is not async.... but [that method relies on `AuthenticationProperties`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/4649449206edae4992e09419334e736726fd2c8e/src/Http/Authentication.Abstractions/src/TokenExtensions.cs#L62) which I don't have readily available from the HttpContextAccessor?

My current workaround (or 'solution'?) is to do the work myself:

```
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers
    .TryGetValue("Authorization", out var authorizationHeader);

var bearerToken = authorizationHeader
    .SingleOrDefault()
    ?.Replace("bearer ", "", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bearerToken))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(httpContextAccessor), "HttpContextAccessor resulted in no Access Token");
}

_client.SetBearerToken(token);
```

How could I *synchronously* get the `access_token` from a `IHttpContextAccessor` without writing my own entire headers/string manipulation helper function to extract it from the Headers?

Comment: You _could_ not assign the token to the client, but rather to each HttpRequestMessage; at that point you’re going to be async anyway. You just need to SendAsync() the messages instead of GetAsync(), PutAsync(), etc.